# Transformation of normal vector

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

I have a problem with an exercises I am doing. The setting is the following. We have a differentiable one to one map $$\phi : \Omega \to \phi(\Omega) \subset \mathbb{R}^3$$
such that $\det(D\phi) > 0 $ everywhere. We suppose $\Omega$ and $\phi(\Omega)$ are open and bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3,$ with smooth boundary and that $\phi$ maps the boundary to the boundary. The problem is to prove that $$(D\phi)^{-T}n(x) = n^{\phi}(\phi(x))$$ where $n$ and $n^{\phi}$ are the normal vectors to the two surfaces at the given points.

The problem is that intuition (and the little bit of differential geometry I know) makes me believe that actually $$(D\phi) n(x) = n^{\phi}(\phi(x))$$is true. For example because $D \phi$ maps tangent vectors to tangent vectors, and hence also the normal vector to the first tangent space to a normal vector for the second tangent space.

Is my reasoning wrong? Thanks for help! ;)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notation $A^{-°T}$ for a linear isomorphism $A$, what is meant here?

Comment: Sorry it's a typo -T stands for inverse transposed.

Comment: If you have doubts it's a good idea, to check an easy example. I suggest as $\Omega$ the unit ball with boundary $S^2$ and as $\phi$ a some map in $SO(3)$. The differential of $\phi$ is again $\phi$ and the unit outer normal of $\vec x \in S^2$ is $\vec x$. So the outer normal af $\phi(\vec x)$ is $\phi(\vec x) = d \phi (\vec x)$ and concerning this example, I agree with your intuition. A general proof may start by noting, that if $F: U \to \partial \Omega$ is a local parametrization of the boundary of $\Omega$, than $\phi \circ F$ is a local parametrization of the boundary of $\phi (\Omega)$.

Comment: Thanks,  I'll try to write that down ;)